# Convert private key in PEM format

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate with Java code and added into KeyStore. Now I want to  export Private key and Certificate created, into a file in PEM format. Is it possible to achieve this without any third party library ? Below is the code I use for creating self-singed certificate.

```
  public void createSelfSignedSSLCertificate() {
    try {            
        final CertAndKeyGen keypair = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA1WithRSA", null);
        final X500Name x500Name =
            new X500Name(commonName, organizationalUnit, organization, city, state, country);
        keypair.generate(keysize);
        final PrivateKey privKey = keypair.getPrivateKey();
        final X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
        chain[0] = keypair.getSelfCertificate(x500Name, new Date(), validity * 24 * 60 * 60);
        final String alias = JettySSLConfiguration.SSL_CERTIFICATE_ALIAS;
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, privKey, keyStorePassword.toCharArray(), chain);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
       // Handle Exception
    }       
}
```

Any suggestion of how to export the key and certificate into file with PEM format will be really helpful.

Comment: There is really no such thing as a single "PEM" format. There are all kinds of different crypto structures that, when base64 encoded and surrounding with `-----BEGIN <xyz>` and `-----END <xyz>`, are described as "PEM format". You'll need to be specific as to which one you want.

Comment: Instead of using some of the internal `sun.*` packages, which are not part of the J2SE API, you should probably consider using a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 11):

You use [Certificate.getEncoded()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getEncoded%28%29) and [Key.getEncoded()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29) to get DER and do the base 64 encoding and header/footer manually, e.g. using [DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte%5B%5D%29) or some other way.  Something like:

```
certpem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
          DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(chain[0].getEncoded())) +
          "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
keypem  = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
          DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(privKey.getEncoded())) +
          "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

Comment: The encoding returned by `[Private]Key.getEncoded()` is and always was, as documented, PKCS8, and the correct PEM type for PKCS8 is and was `PRIVATE KEY` (as in Anup's more recent A) _not_ `RSA PRIVATE KEY`. This is formalized in RFC7468, although that was 2 years after this A.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Daniel Roethlisberger, for your reply.
I got great help from your reply..

Implements in Java as below

```
String encodedString = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
            encodedString = encodedString+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Enrollment2.getKey().getEncoded())+"\n";
            encodedString = encodedString+"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android, you can use the following Kotlin extension function:

```
import android.util.Base64
import java.security.PublicKey

fun PublicKey.toPemString(): String {
    val publicKeyBase64: String = Base64.encodeToString(this.encoded, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    return publicKeyBase64.chunked(64).joinToString(
        separator = "\n",
        prefix = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
        postfix = "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
    )
}
```