# Convert RSAPublicKey to PEM

Tags: java, rsa, public-key, pem

I created RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey using the code below in Java. I want to convert this to PEM key with something starting with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and ends with
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

```
 KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
 keyGenerator.initialize(2048);
 KeyPair keyPair = keyGenerator.genKeyPair();
 RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
 RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
```

My publicKey looks like this

```
 Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
 modulus: 24725677929965393399116311796579849208456694139830747885329642050536871708602127467509375984842143051004691282429145783432620678099378069556446495267888717074390817963266933346714989616542462975355537898417850941217923441420844383641690704416493960652901568109149478965331966323480000341094954977708922888113451561712134246092055663913101815995378690422053526513288907318201617969755234493423112606856093576711535203464948727407631244156513571088601573017696719030247683899442955936480784619914188425390154747719569488556784397642039320538767824471814998647925121013750739910552195629468326354683709340318053920864663
 public exponent: 65537
```

Comment: use the `publicKey.getEncoded()` method to get the byte array, base64 encode the bytes, put newlines after every 64 characters, then wrap it in the  BEGIN and END lines.

Comment: @JamesKPolk can you write it as an answer?

Comment: It will be something like:

`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsaPublicKey.getEncoded(), "UTF-8");`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425875/convert-private-key-in-pem-format/