# Programatically convert a JKS to PEM

Tags: java, converters, pem, jks

I need to convert a JKS (password protected) in to a .PEM containing the KeyPairs (or selected alias) for other services to use.

So far, I have written this:

```
 @Transactional
public ResponseEntity<String> getPublicKeyFromJKS(long jksid) {
    try {
        //1. Lift the entity
        JKSFile jksFile = jksFileRepo.getOne(jksid);

        //2. Get the Object from S3
        S3Object object = getS3ObjectService.getS3Object(jksFile.getS3ObjectKey());
        System.out.println(object.getObjectContent().getHttpRequest());
        InputStream in = object.getObjectContent();

        //3. Make KeyStore...
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(in, rsaConfig.getKeystorePassword().toCharArray());

        //4. Get keys to PEM formatted file.
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("access", rsaConfig.getKeystorePassword().toCharArray());
        Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate("access");
        PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);


        System.out.println(keyPair.getPrivate().toString());
        System.out.println(keyPair.getPublic().toString());
```

I am pulling the requested JKS from my amazon S3 bucket and reading the Private and Public key without issue...but I would now like to be able to put them in to a PEM formatted keystore (for use by another service).

Thanks for any suggestions! I want this programatically...not using the java command line keytool.

Comment: A pem is not a keystore, it is a base64 encoded der, which is itself a format for storing a single key OR certificate. Therefore it's not possible to convert a keystore to a pem - you either need to convert it to several pems or only convert a single item from the keystore.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457790/671988

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. So I guess my question is really "How can I get a key from a JKS and put it as PEM formatted with its certificate"?

Comment: [This (rather outdated) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425875/convert-private-key-in-pem-format) explains how to write out a pem. See also the [new `Base64` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). Basically write out the key and certificate separately - traditionally the key would have the `.key` extension and the certificate `.pem` - also it is with encrypting the exported key - but that's a different question.